# re-attach cassandra keyspace tables files after re-install

Tags: cassandra

I had to re-install casssandra on a single node windows box but now the keyspace has gone.  I have a copy of the data/ folder with a subfolder for each column family but I'm really stuck how to re-attach that folder so my keyspace is completely restored.

I really need the data back :\

Comment: Finally fixed this.  I rebuilt the keyspace table structures using the DDL produced in DBeaver on another machine.  Run that on the server box to regenerate the structure.  Then copy the contents of each subfolder containing the data into the newly created (empty) folders for each table (column family).  The folder names will have different GUID's stuck to the end so that's why I just copied the contents.  Restart the Datastax Cassandra service and I'm running again.